# Acessing a wordpress database from an iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, wordpress

I've been asked to create an app that will get data back from a database where the CMS will be Wordpress. I've never used a CMS so I'm trying to get a (overview)picture in my head of how it could all work and what each of the components would be. And what a CMS actually brings to the party.

Creating the app itself is pretty clear. I've done a few already. I've made a database before and shouldnt cause a problem.

But what is going to be in the middle between the app and the database?

Part A:
I'm guessing iphone apps typically would call some php file that's hosted on the server? The php then would make a call to the database and return the data somehow, maybe as xml. But this is really basic and wouldnt require a CMS. Just a database and a phpfile, or am I wrong?

Part B:
If i wanted to run a check on the database every minute to see if any of the data in database was no longer valid and remove it if needed, that would require somekind of program running on the server. So that program would be Wordpress, since it is managing the content, so a content management system is actually needed and is for these kind of taskes. Am i understanding the role of CMS?

Many Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part A**: Yes, that's definitely how it would normally work. Of course, you're not accessing "a" database, you're accessing the database WordPress creates, but otherwise, sure.

**Part B**: The role of a CMS is to provide a structured, easily-edited way of presenting information. It abstracts both the database and the user interface stuff, allowing the CMS administrator to CRUD data via the use of simple forms.

In your case, no, you wouldn't (usually) ask the WordPress software to provide information because it's not set up to provide data that's programmatically requested. Instead it's designed to display HTML pages with the data embedded. The WordPress software is specifically for humans to CRUD the data through a human-friendly interface. You'd write your own, as in Part A.

**[This article](http://stylizedweb.com/2008/06/20/grab-data-from-wordpress-database/)** shows some basic PHP for retrieving blog entries and user comments, likely most of what you'd want. The WordPress database format is well-documented: **[here's an article](http://www.blokeish.com/2010/09/extracting-data-from-wordpress-database-and-convert-into-xml-format/)** that lays it out and provides more PHP examples for retrieving the information.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, I guess I know to little and need to go and get the basics of the client server stuff before learning about more high level stuff like wordpress.

Comment: Well, I would actually ask WordPress to provide info, as it does have an XML-RPC API especially for that purpose :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look how the Wordpress for iOS team is doing it:

http://ios.wordpress.org/development/

Answer (score 1):

I would not try to access the db directly or through some custom php-code, but use [the official WordPress API](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) (which uses xml-rpc) instead.

and [this xml-rpc objective-c library](https://github.com/eczarny/xmlrpc) might even make this a pretty straightforward exercise?