# How to take dynamically take data from a website and add it to an iPhone app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, database, content-management-system

Someone asked me to take a [website](http://www.laloyolan.com/)  and pull a feed of its stories, images, features (such as polls) and output that data into a mobile app.

I was told the website was powered by Wordpress, but that may have been a mistake because the site linked to [this](http://www.townnews365.com/content_management_solutions/about_blox/) instead. Either way, the website is designed with WYSIWYG tools.

I don't have any experience with PHP, databases, JSON, or XML, so I'm trying to find the quickest way to learn how to accomplish this task.

Another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486692/acessing-a-wordpress-database-from-an-iphone-app) discusses something similar but with Wordpress. Other than the links being wordpress specific, I was hoping I could get a more thorough explanation so that a beginner like me could understand.

Also, there is some [documentation](http://docs.townnews.com/kbpublisher/) for the company that powers the site, but I don't know what I should be searching for.

I hope I don't come off as someone who is asking others to do all the work for me. I've looked around the internet for some resources, but I'm still confused as to how I should begin this process.

Thank you

Comment: This is a pretty vague question, all I can really recommend is read up on how to parse RSS and other types of feeds. Use whatever example data they give you as reference, and parse it into data to presented in your app. If they have any pre-made mobile web components as part of their CMS maybe integrate web views with those.

Comment: I didn't even notice that the website has RSS feeds. I can probably take it from here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good article how to do that here: [Tutorial: Building An RSS Reader](http://maniacdev.com/2011/01/tutorial-building-an-rss-reader/)

Comment: I skimmed through the article, and I have a couple of syntactical questions: Are things like  `@synthesize blogTitle = _blogTitle;` and `_blogTitle = [blogTitle copy];` an older way of synthesizing properties, or is it separate from something like `@synthesize blogTitle`?

Comment: It is a way of synthesizing while giving the ivar names at the same time. In the latest Xcode 4.5, you don't even need to synthesize the properties anymore, it is automatically done for you and the ivars with underscore are also assumed.